# Check User Input String in array with case in esac?

Tags: case, ksh

I am trying to write a ksh shell script in bash to check a user entered string is equal to the element stored in array.

```
loc_ora=/etc/oratab
osid=`sed -nr 's/^(.*):\/.*$/\1/p' $loc_ora`
set -A arr $osid
OIFS=$IFS;
IFS=" ";
read usid
case "${arr[*]}" in
    * /$usid/ *)
        echo -e " \t\t Entered SID Matches ... \n"
        ORACLE_SID=$usid
        echo -e " \t\t SID: $ORACLE_SID \n"
        export ORACLE_SID
        export ORACLE_HOME
        ;;
    *)
        sleep 03
        echo -e " \t\t Entered SID Does not Match the System !!! \n \t\t Please Re-run the Script with a Valid SID."
        sleep 02
        echo -e " \t\t ABORTING !!! ..."
        sleep 03
        exit 0
        ;;
 esac
IFS=$OIFS;

Error/scenario1:
I am facing a syntax error: `/' unexpected if I keep /$usid/.

Error/scenario2:
If I remove the // and keep like *$usid* in the pattern, I do not face any error but only the second *) half pattern is printing even when I provide the correct SID.
```

How do I do this validation? Please help.

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest checking entered uid against /etc/oratab differently:

```
    read uid
    loc_ora=/etc/oratab
    sed -nr 's/^(.*):\/.*$/\1/p' $loc_ora | grep -q "^$uid\$" 
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "sid valid"
    else
        echo "sid Not Valid"
    Fi
```

Comment: Thanks it works like charm. I changed the script with my requirement. So there is no need of array too right?

Comment: Oh Man for this single liner command I was trembling here and there for 5 days. Thanks Man.

Comment: May I know or Can you explain how or what does these lines do?      sed -nr 's/^(.*):\/.*$/\1/p' $loc_ora | grep -q "^$uid\$" --> grep - q will extract the entered string ? 
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]  -- > No Idea what this $ and ? do here..

Comment: The sed line if you noticed is exactly same as in your original solution and it just select the sids from /etc/oratab by droping out everything else. The substitute command `s` is mathing the entire line by selecting only intrested part **`(.*)`** and then its [the line] being replaced with selectedstring only **`\\1`**.

Comment: The sed line if is exactly same as in your original solution and it just select the sids from /etc/oratab by droping out everything else. The substitute command `s` is mathing the entire line by selecting only interested part **`(.*)`** and then its [the line] being replaced with selectedstring only **`\1`**. Then the output [sid ids] goes to input via pipe to grep and grep is searching for your input sid just that it does this quietly **`-q`** [we don't need grep output here]. Result can be checked from grep exit code which can be checked using the last executed exit code **`$?`**.

Comment: And regarding `^` and `$` around $uid is to make sure you'll not find a partialy matching string. I.e input uid is user but in /etc/oratab you have user1 user2 user etc. So that is to ensure grep will search exactly for your input only.